# Xamarin WebViewClient onLoadResource/onPageFinished

Tags: android, webview, xamarin

Hi im trying to create a WebView application, and i want to create a waiting dialog until the page is loaded.

However i have tried different solutions but i cannot figure out why this is not working when it is working for others on the internet. it fails in Xamarin saying that "}" is missing after this line webview.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {, even that im sure that i remembered the }); at then end.

it seems that it cannot create something inside the webview.SetWebViewClient().

```
    webview.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            //code to show dialog
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //code to dismiss dialog
        }

    });
```

Comment: You are using C#  for coding  in `Xamarin` ? because posted code is written in Java

Comment: Ok so my problem is that C# not allowing functions/voids inside the SetWebViewClient(). I also tried creating like the example Step7 from http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/

But then i cannot even make a Toast.MakeText becouse its not inside the main class or something.

Comment: what problem you are getting using provided link?

Comment: creating onloadresource/onpagefinished with a loading dialog or toast..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add WebViewClient to WebView and show Toast message from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`  in C# you will need to create a class by extending `WebViewClient`  as:

```
public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
  public Activity mActivity;
  public HelloWebViewClient(Activity mActivity){
   this.mActivity=mActivity
  }
  public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
                view.LoadUrl (url);
                Toast.MakeText (mActivity, "Toast Message", 
                                     ToastLength.Long).Show();
                return true;
        }
}
```

and use `HelloWebViewClient` class constructor to pass activity Context:

```
web_view.SetWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient (this));
```